# PiCamera 1.13 docs MMAL example problem

Tags: python-3, picamera, mmal

I am trying to lower the time to capture a still image from the Pi camera (I have a V2 and HQ).  To this end, I have found my way to the PiCamera 1.13 docs, specifically chapter 16 dealing with the MMAL object.  I tried following the example code given between 16.1.1 and 16.1.7, which seems to be a basic set-up and capture.
I reduced the code to the minimum I thought would work; there is a lot of input and output confirmation I removed.  Here is the code:

```
from picamera import mmal, mmalobj as mo
import io

def image_callback(port, buf):
    output.write(buf.data)
    return bool(buf.flags & mmal.MMAL_BUFFER_HEADER_FLAG_FRAME_END)

camera = mo.MMALCamera()
preview = mo.MMALRenderer()

camera.outputs[2].format = mmal.MMAL_ENCODING_RGB24
camera.outputs[2].framesize = (640, 480)
camera.outputs[2].commit()
camera.outputs[2]
camera.outputs[2].enable()
camera.outputs[2].disable()

output = io.open('image.data', 'wb')

camera.outputs[2].enable(image_callback)
output.tell()

camera.outputs[2].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_CAPTURE] = True
camera.outputs[2].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_CAPTURE] = False
output.tell()
camera.outputs[2].disable()
output.close()
```

This code runs without error from a file, cam_test.py, but produces the file image.data of size 0 bytes.  However, when the code is run interactively from the Python console, as the examples do, the desired file is created properly only when the code is entered in parts.  That is, I can paste the code up to the first `output.tell()`, then copy & paste the remaining code (the image capture) into the console and have success.  This tells me I have the code to create the image file; why does it not work from a Python file?
I have checked Python versions in both cases is the same (3.7.3) and use a Python virtual environment.
Thanks in advance for any input.

Edit: The second part of the code is the last 5 lines

```
camera.outputs[2].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_CAPTURE] = True
camera.outputs[2].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_CAPTURE] = False
output.tell()
camera.outputs[2].disable()
output.close()
```

I had tried a 1 second delay between the two parts (in the .py file); still image.data file of 0 bytes.

Comment: Could it be a timing issue?  It will take a few seconds to post the second part of the code and wonder if that’s needed - maybe adding a sleep would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it appears it ***is*** a timing issue.  I modified the code to include a loop to capture an image and finish when the size of `image.data` is greater than zero.  Obviously slower than the first version but it appears we can't rush the pi camera.
I would prefer not to import two io/os type modules so will look into that, and also whether both forms of CAPTURE are required in the loop.

```
while (os.path.getsize('image.data') == 0):
    camera.outputs[2].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_CAPTURE] = True
    camera.outputs[2].params[mmal.MMAL_PARAMETER_CAPTURE] = False
```